# powercli script on linux is failing to run as systemctl service

Tags: linux, powershell, powercli, systemctl

I'm trying to create a powercli script (ps1) to run on linux as a systemctl service.
The script is working fine when running with pwsh. But when I turn it into a service it fails as if not recognizing the pwsh commands that I'm using in the script.

```
[Unit]
Description=test
After=network-online.target

[Service]
user=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pwsh /build/test/test.ps1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The error I see in journalctl:

```
Connect-VIServer: /build/test.ps1:7
Line |
7 |  Connect-VIServer -Server $vc
|  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| The term 'Connect-VIServer' is not recognized as a name of a
| cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check
| the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
| that the path is correct and try again.
get-vm: /build/self_healing/start_network_adapter.ps1:9
Line |
9 |  get-vm $node | get-networkadapter | where {$_.connectionstate.connect …
|  ~~~~~~
| The term 'get-vm' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet,
| function, script file, or executable program. Check the
| spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
| the path is correct and try again.
(7.2.4:A:80) [NamedPipeIPC_ServerListenerError:NamedPipe.Exception.Error] An error has occurred in PowerShell IPC listening thread on process: 61158 in AppDomain: None.  Error Message: Operation canceled.
```

Why does this pwsh script runs fine normally but fails when executed as a systemctl service?

Comment: Does it recognise non-PowerrCLi commands? If so then it's the module thats not available - did you install it for all users or just one user profile?

Comment: Seems like powershell commands are working fine.

Comment: Modules are load on demand and in Windows are stored with the user profile by default or optionally for "AllUsers" in a system path so that they can be loaded. Presumably Linux does something similar and systemctl needs to know where the modules are?

Comment: I manage to solve it.
Apparently, the issue was with this line: `user=root` in the service definition file. `user` should be with capital: `User`. So it didn't run it as root and therefore couldn't access the modules.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve it. Apparently, the issue was with this line: `user=root` in the service definition file. `user` should be with capital: `User`. So it didn't run it as root and therefore couldn't access the modules.